# .OBJLoader, weird indices numbers

Tags: c++, opengl, file-io, import, 3dsmax

I've been messing with OpenGL and c++ lately (with FreeGLUT and GLEW) and started to try and import .obj files from 3DS Max 2014. Everything is fine if i manual type the vertices and indices but, when trying to get them from a file i get strange numbers.
when getting the indices instead of 1 there was 1000 and instead of 3 there was 3965 and when there was a 12 is was 1212 (there are ones and threes etc but sometimes they are random)

Here is the code I use to import: http://pastebin.com/1ds6fgj9

or

```
std::vector<std::string> Object::split(std::string str, char splitter){

char charText[1000];
int number = 0;
int numberOfWords = 0;
char current[10][100];

std::vector<std::string> tokens;

strcpy(charText, str.c_str());

int size = sizeof(charText) / sizeof(*charText);
//std::cout << size << " size\n";
for (int i = 0; i < splitter; i++){
    if (charText[i] == splitter){
        tokens.push_back(current[numberOfWords]);
        numberOfWords++;
        number = 0;
    }
    else{
        current[numberOfWords][number] = charText[i];
        number++;
    }
}

return tokens;
}

Object::Object(std::string fileName, Vector3f pos, Vector3f rot, float Size, Vector3f color){
Position = pos;
Rotation = rot;
size = Size;



colors = color;


std::string data;
std::ifstream file(fileName);
std::string line;


Vector3f _verts[1024];
int noVerts = 0;

unsigned int _inds[1024];
int noIndices = 0;

while (getline(file, line))  // same as: while (getline( myfile, line ).good())
{

    char charText[1024];
    strcpy(charText, line.c_str());



    if (charText[0] == 'v' && charText[1] != 'n' && charText[1] != 't'){

        std::vector<std::string> splitLine = split(line, ' ');
        _verts[noVerts] = Vector3f(atoi(splitLine[1].c_str()), atoi(splitLine[2].c_str()), atoi(splitLine[3].c_str()));

        //std::cout << "Vertices Number:" << noVerts << " x:" << _verts[noVerts].getX() << " y:" << _verts[noVerts].getY() << " z:" << _verts[noVerts].getZ() << "\n";
        noVerts++;
    }

    if (charText[0] == 'f'){
        std::vector<std::string> splitLine = split(line, ' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            std::vector<std::string> ssl = split(splitLine[i+1], '/');

            //std::cout << atoi(splitLine[i].c_str()) << "\n";

            std::cout << i << ": " << atoi(ssl[0].c_str()) << " " << atoi(ssl[1].c_str()) << " " << atoi(ssl[2].c_str()) << "\n";

            _inds[noIndices] = atoi(ssl[0].c_str());
            noIndices++;
            _inds[noIndices] = atoi(ssl[1].c_str());
            noIndices++;
            _inds[noIndices] = atoi(ssl[2].c_str());
            noIndices++;

            //std::cout << "number of indices:" << noIndices<< "\n";
        }

    }


}

verts = _verts;
inds = _inds;

SizeV = sizeof(verts);
SizeI = sizeof(inds);



noPoints = SizeI / sizeof(*inds);
length = SizeV / sizeof(*verts);


Matrix4f posM, rotM, sizeM;
sizeM.InitScaleTransform(size, size, size);
rotM.InitRotateTransform(rot.getX(), rot.getY(), rot.getZ());
posM.InitTranslationTransform(pos.getX(), pos.getY(), pos.getZ());

M = posM * rotM * sizeM;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    verts[i] = _verts[i];
}


}
```

I think it is an error in my code when reading the file but if not just ask to see my other code.

[EDIT]

It does this for all obj files (not tried exporting with a different program and the obj files I have tried have very few faces).

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: can you some how add the file so I can test it with my importer?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/y5hjhnl516aj2c2/ballthing.obj

Comment: Upload the material file too please.... (.mtl).

Comment: I'm developing a program called 3DMive (3D Models Importer/Viewer/Exporter), and it loads perfectly fine with my code. http://www.filedropper.com/screenshot_1

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway :) and nice program, looks very professional

Comment: No problem.... Is in the works keep checking 3DMive.com (Sorry for the ad SO).

Comment: I had this issue while developing exporters for 3dsmax (I have made a few to say the least).
The problem on my end was that the numbers that I used for indexing the list went crazy (I'm guessing it started to read outside memory, and then give big numbers back).

You have to check by stepping through and check all places where you index your lists, you can use conditional breakpoints to catch when the value goes over X, to more easily see what's going on when that happens.